# Malloc array of structs in function

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I'm trying to malloc an array of structs, the code works, but I get these warnings, am i doing something wrong?

```
typedef struct BATTLES_s{
    char day_of_the_week[MAX_ARR];
    char date[MAX_ARR];
    char time[MAX_ARR];
    char team_one_name[MAX_ARR];
    char team_two_name[MAX_ARR];
    int  team_one_score;
    int  team_two_score;
    int  peers;
}BATTLES_s;
```

```
int main()
{
 int total_number_of_battles;

 count_number_of_battles(&total_number_of_battles); /* this value is 182 */

 BATTLES_s *battles = malloc(total_number_of_battles * sizeof(*battles));
 malloc_battle_struct(total_number_of_battles,battles);

 print_result();
}
```

```
void malloc_battle_struct(int total_number_of_battles,BATTLES_s battles[MAX_STRUCT_ARRAY]){
 int i;
 for (i = 0; i <= total_number_of_battles; i++)
 {
    *battles[i].date = malloc( sizeof(char) * MAX_ARR );
    *battles[i].day_of_the_week = malloc( sizeof(char) * MAX_ARR );
    *battles[i].team_one_name = malloc( sizeof(int) * MAX_ARR );
    *battles[i].team_two_name = malloc( sizeof(char) * MAX_ARR );
    *battles[i].time = malloc( sizeof(char) * MAX_ARR );
 }
}
```

warning: assignment to 'char' from 'void *' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     *battles[i].date = malloc( sizeof(char) * MAX_ARR );

warning: assignment to 'char' from 'void *' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     *battles[i].day_of_the_week = malloc( sizeof(char) * MAX_ARR );

warning: assignment to 'char' from 'void *' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     *battles[i].team_one_name = malloc( sizeof(int) * MAX_ARR );

warning: assignment to 'char' from 'void *' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     *battles[i].team_two_name = malloc( sizeof(char) * MAX_ARR );

warning: assignment to 'char' from 'void *' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     *battles[i].time = malloc( sizeof(char) * MAX_ARR );

Comment: what does "work" mean in this context? Which C book are you reading? It is not possible to allocate arrays, you have them allocated, everything here is pretty much wrong. In fact you can just remove the `malloc_battle_struct` completely and call to it.

Comment: I am using the arrays later on to store names and scores, and it works. but i think you are right, i don't need the "malloc_battle_struct" at all here..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is completely broken:

```
*battles[i].date = malloc( sizeof(char) * MAX_ARR );
```

As the compiler has told you, you are assigning a pointer where it does not belong.  `date` is a character array, you cannot store the result of `malloc` there.  It's as if you think you are dynamically allocating strings, when you have already storage space for the strings inside your struct.

Comment: So I don't need to do anything after I have done:
"BATTLES_s *battles = malloc(total_number_of_battles * sizeof(*battles));"?

Comment: @MetalMike: Each struct contains storage space and does not contain any pointers.  So yes your single `malloc()` allocates space for everything.

Answer (score 1):

There seem issue with concept of static and dynamic allocation. You have declared various array in structure which are statically allocated and don't require malloc.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have dynamic string fields in your struct you should declare them as character pointers. I corrected your code with comments.

`malloc` function returns `void*` so you should cast the returned value to the type you dynamically allocating.

`malloc` function allocates area from the heap. Thus, it is your responsibility to deallocate that area with `free` function when you're done.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_ARR 100

typedef struct BATTLES_s{
    char* day_of_the_week;
    char* date;
    char* time;
    char* team_one_name;
    char* team_two_name;
    int  team_one_score;
    int  team_two_score;
    int  peers;
}BATTLES_s;

void malloc_battle_struct(int total_number_of_battles, BATTLES_s *battles)
{
  
    // it should be less than '<' total_number_of_battles otherwise you get 
    //segmentation fault
    for (int i = 0; i < total_number_of_battles; i++) 
    {
        // *battles[i] is incorrect battles[i] already dereferencing ith pointer
        battles[i].date = (char*) malloc( sizeof(char) * MAX_ARR );
        battles[i].day_of_the_week = (char*)malloc( sizeof(char) * MAX_ARR );
        battles[i].team_one_name = (char*)malloc( sizeof(char) * MAX_ARR );
        battles[i].team_two_name = (char*)malloc( sizeof(char) * MAX_ARR );
        battles[i].time = (char*)malloc( sizeof(char) * MAX_ARR );
    }
}

int main()
{
    int total_number_of_battles = 182; // I assume it is returned from your 
//count_number_of_battles function
    BATTLES_s *battles = (BATTLES_s*) malloc(total_number_of_battles * 
    sizeof(BATTLES_s));
    malloc_battle_struct(total_number_of_battles, battles);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char date[MAX_ARR];
```

by writting this in your struct you made a static allocation of memory (MAX_ARR) for date in the BSS, if you want to dynamically allocate memory you need to use pointer:

```
char *date;
date = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_ARR);
```